Can't build mysql-haskell library
I can't install mysql-haskell lib with different versions of haskell, i try 9.8.2
9.6.6 and 9.4.8, two of them are provided in stackage snapshots https://www.stackage.org/package/mysql-haskell/snapshots - so I expected that it must work together if I use corresponding versions with cabal and docker, but in reality this is not happening, what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?
ps. Also I find that 20 days ago my container was build without errors with same configuration so I can run it now and see in console:
 "Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' is 20 days old.
hservant-1  | Run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available packages.
",

but now I guess the cabal update in new builds bring this error..
this is my docker
FROM haskell:9.8.2
#FROM haskell:9.6.6
#FROM haskell:9.4.8

WORKDIR /opt/p1

RUN cabal update && cabal install haskell-language-server

# Add just the .cabal file to capture dependencies
COPY ./herror.cabal /opt/p1/herror.cabal

# Docker will cache this command as a layer, freeing us up to
# modify source code without re-installing dependencies
# (unless the .cabal file changes!)
RUN cabal build --only-dependencies -j4
#RUN cabal v2-install --only-dependencies -j4

# Add and Install Application Code
COPY . /opt/p1
RUN cabal install

#CMD ["p1"]
CMD ["cabal", "run"]

this is my p1.cabal
cabal-version:      3.0
name:               p1    
version:            0.1.0.0
license:            NONE   
author:             dmitr
maintainer:         dmitr3232@gmail.com
build-type:         Simple
extra-doc-files:    CHANGELOG.md

common warnings
    ghc-options: -Wall

executable p1
    import:           warnings
    main-is:          Main.hs
    build-depends:    base,
                      -- base ^>=4.17.2.1,
                      -- tls==1.5.8,
                      mysql-haskell==1.1.6

    hs-source-dirs:   app    
    default-language: Haskell2010

I got this errors:
265.1 [17 of 24] Compiling Paths_mysql_haskell ( dist/build/autogen/Paths_mysql_haskell.hs, dist/build/Paths_mysql_haskell.o, dist/build/Paths_mysql_haskell.dyn_o )
265.1 [18 of 24] Compiling Data.TLSSetting  ( src/Data/TLSSetting.hs, dist/build/Data/TLSSetting.o, dist/build/Data/TLSSetting.dyn_o )
265.1 
265.1 src/Data/TLSSetting.hs:70:35: error: [GHC-39999]
265.1     • No instance for ‘Data.Default.Class.Default TLS.Supported’
265.1         arising from a use of ‘def’
265.1     • In the expression: def
265.1       In a record update at field ‘TLS.supportedCiphers’,
265.1       with type constructor ‘TLS.Supported’
265.1       and data constructor ‘tls-2.1.4:Network.TLS.Parameters.Supported’.
265.1       In the expression:
265.1         def {TLS.supportedCiphers = TLS.ciphersuite_default}
265.1    |
265.1 70 |         {   TLS.clientSupported = def { TLS.supportedCiphers = TLS.ciphersuite_default }
265.1    |                                   ^^^
265.1 
265.1 src/Data/TLSSetting.hs:71:35: error: [GHC-39999]
265.1     • No instance for ‘Data.Default.Class.Default TLS.Shared’
265.1         arising from a use of ‘def’
265.1     • In the expression: def
265.1       In a record update at fields ‘TLS.sharedCAStore’,
265.1                                    ‘TLS.sharedValidationCache’,
265.1       with type constructor ‘TLS.Shared’
265.1       and data constructor ‘tls-2.1.4:Network.TLS.Parameters.Shared’.
265.1       In the expression:
265.1         def {TLS.sharedCAStore = caStore, TLS.sharedValidationCache = def}
265.1    |
265.1 71 |         ,   TLS.clientShared    = def
265.1    |                                   ^^^
265.1 
265.1 src/Data/TLSSetting.hs:73:45: error: [GHC-39999]
265.1     • No instance for ‘Data.Default.Class.Default TLS.ValidationCache’
265.1         arising from a use of ‘def’
265.1     • In the expression: def
265.1       In a record update at fields ‘TLS.sharedCAStore’,
265.1                                    ‘TLS.sharedValidationCache’,
265.1       with type constructor ‘TLS.Shared’
265.1       and data constructor ‘tls-2.1.4:Network.TLS.Parameters.Shared’.
265.1       In the expression:
265.1         def {TLS.sharedCAStore = caStore, TLS.sharedValidationCache = def}
265.1    |
265.1 73 |             ,   TLS.sharedValidationCache = def
265.1    |                                             ^^^
265.1 
265.1 src/Data/TLSSetting.hs:115:20: error: [GHC-39999]
265.1     • No instance for ‘Data.Default.Class.Default TLS.ServerParams’
265.1         arising from a use of ‘def’
265.1     • In the expression: def
265.1       In a record update at fields ‘TLS.serverCACertificates’,
265.1                                    ‘TLS.serverShared’, ‘TLS.serverSupported’,
265.1       with type constructor ‘TLS.ServerParams’
265.1       and data constructor ‘tls-2.1.4:Network.TLS.Parameters.ServerParams’.
265.1       In the first argument of ‘return’, namely
265.1         ‘def
265.1            {TLS.serverCACertificates = c'',
265.1             TLS.serverShared = def
265.1                                  {TLS.sharedCredentials = TLS.Credentials [c']},
265.1             TLS.serverSupported = def
265.1                                     {TLS.supportedCiphers = TLS.ciphersuite_strong}}’
265.1     |
265.1 115 |             return def
265.1     |                    ^^^
265.1 [19 of 24] Compiling System.IO.Streams.TCP ( src/System/IO/Streams/TCP.hs, dist/build/System/IO/Streams/TCP.o, dist/build/System/IO/Streams/TCP.dyn_o )
265.1 [20 of 24] Compiling Database.MySQL.Connection ( src/Database/MySQL/Connection.hs, dist/build/Database/MySQL/Connection.o, dist/build/Database/MySQL/Connection.dyn_o )
265.1 [21 of 24] Compiling Database.MySQL.Base ( src/Database/MySQL/Base.hs, dist/build/Database/MySQL/Base.o, dist/build/Database/MySQL/Base.dyn_o )
265.1 [22 of 24] Compiling Database.MySQL.BinLog ( src/Database/MySQL/BinLog.hs, dist/build/Database/MySQL/BinLog.o, dist/build/Database/MySQL/BinLog.dyn_o )
265.1 Error: cabal: Failed to build mysql-haskell-1.1.6. See the build log above for
265.1 details.
265.1 
------
Dockerfile:15
--------------------
  13 |     # modify source code without re-installing dependencies
  14 |     # (unless the .cabal file changes!)
  15 | >>> RUN cabal build --only-dependencies -j4
  16 |     #RUN cabal v2-install --only-dependencies -j4
  17 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cabal build --only-dependencies -j4" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I try to downgrade to mysql-haskell==1.5.0 and lower but this always involves tls lib build error like:
174.8 [38 of 76] Compiling Network.TLS.Credentials ( Network/TLS/Credentials.hs, dist/build/Network/TLS/Credentials.o, dist/build/Network/TLS/Credentials.dyn_o )
174.8 [39 of 76] Compiling Network.TLS.Parameters ( Network/TLS/Parameters.hs, dist/build/Network/TLS/Parameters.o, dist/build/Network/TLS/Parameters.dyn_o )
174.8 
174.8 Network/TLS/Parameters.hs:404:39: error: [GHC-39999]
174.8     • No instance for ‘Default ValidationCache’
174.8         arising from a use of ‘def’
174.8     • In the ‘sharedValidationCache’ field of a record
174.8       In the expression:
174.8         Shared
174.8           {sharedCredentials = mempty,
174.8            sharedSessionManager = noSessionManager, sharedCAStore = mempty,
174.8            sharedValidationCache = def, sharedHelloExtensions = []}
174.8       In an equation for ‘def’:
174.8           def
174.8             = Shared
174.8                 {sharedCredentials = mempty,
174.8                  sharedSessionManager = noSessionManager, sharedCAStore = mempty,
174.8                  sharedValidationCache = def, sharedHelloExtensions = []}
174.8     |
174.8 404 |             , sharedValidationCache = def
174.8     |                                       ^^^
174.8 Error: cabal: Failed to build tls-2.0.6 (which is required by
174.8 mysql-haskell-1.1.5). See the build log above for details.
174.8 
------
Dockerfile:15
--------------------
  13 |     # modify source code without re-installing dependencies
  14 |     # (unless the .cabal file changes!)
  15 | >>> RUN cabal build --only-dependencies -j4
  16 |     #RUN cabal v2-install --only-dependencies -j4
  17 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cabal build --only-dependencies -j4" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Interesting that tls lib itself builded without mysql-haskell, but then I add mysql-haskell I got all this errors.

What if you add tls >=1.2.0 as a dependency?

@willeM_VanOnsem same error " No instance for ‘Default ValidationCache’"

These errors with Default are because there are duplicate copies of the Default class: one from newer versions of the package data-default (>= 0.8) and one from older versions of data-default-class (< 0.2).
You need to keep those in sync: either use only old versions or only new versions of data-default and data-default-class.
mysql-haskell has a dependency data-default-class < 0.2, so I would suggest adding data-default < 0.8 to your package.
Another solution may be to require new versions by ignoring the upper bound and adding lower bounds data-default-class >= 0.2 && data-default >= 0.8.
